# How to access a tuple inside a 2d list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a 2d list like this:

```
[[0, (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3)], 
 [(1, 4), (3, 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y')], 
 [(2, 1), (1, 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y')],
 [(3, 1), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y'),('x', 'y')]]
```

I want to access and work with just the first element(index 0) of each tuple.

How can I do that in python?

Comment: Your first item in the first row is not a tuple.

Comment: I know, but I want to access the tuple's[0]

Comment: @RafaelÁquila Where do you want these first tuples items to be? in a list? in another tuple? get them by some indexes ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear to me, but if I understood correctly, `first` is a list of the first items in any tuple in the 2D list.

```
arr = [[0, (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3)],
[(1, 4), (3, 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y')],
[(2, 1), (1, 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y')],
[(3, 1), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y'),('x', 'y')]]

firsts = []
for row in arr:
    for tup in row:
        if not isinstance(tup, tuple):
            continue
        firsts.append(tup[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me, either, but you can use the following if you want the items not in tuples in addition to the first item in a tuple:

```
og = [[0, (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3)],
     [(1, 4), (3, 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y')],
     [(2, 1), (1, 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y')],
     [(3, 1), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y'),('x', 'y')]]
firsts = [x[0] if isinstance(x, tuple) else x for y in og for x in y]
```

If you're only looking for items with a tuple, move the logic around a bit like this:

```
firsts = [x[0] for y in og for x in y if isinstance(x, tuple)]
```